# PHP - json_decode - issues decoding string

Tags: php, json

I'm playing with the API from deepl.com that provides automatic translations. I call the API through cURL and I get a json string in return which appears to be fine but cannot be decoded by PHP for some reason.

Let me show first how I make the cURL call :-

```
$content = "bonjour <caption>monsieur</caption> madame";
$url = 'https://api.deepl.com/v2/translate';
$fields = array(
        'text' => $content,
        'target_lang' => $lg,
        'tag_handling' => 'xml',
        'ignore_tags' => 'caption',
        'auth_key' => 'my_api_key');

$fields_string = "";
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) 
    { 
        $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; 
    }

rtrim($fields_string, '&');

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded','Content-Length: '. strlen($fields_string)));  

$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```

If at this stage I do

```
echo $result;
```

I get:

```
{"translations":[{"detected_source_language":"FR","text":"Hola <caption>monsieur</caption> Señora"}]}
```

Which seems ok to me. Then if I use code below -

```
echo gettype($result);
```

I get "string" which is still ok but now, the following code fails:

```
$result = json_decode($result,true);
print_r($result);
```

The output is empty!

If I now do something like this:

```
$test = '{"translations":[{"detected_source_language":"FR","text":"Hola <caption>monsieur</caption> Señora"}]}';
echo gettype($test);
$test = json_decode($test,true);
print_r($test);
```

I get a perfectly fine array:

```
(
[translations] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [detected_source_language] => FR
                [text] => Hola <caption>monsieur</caption> Señora
            )

    )

)
```

I did nothing else than copy/pasting the content from the API to a static variable and it works but coming from the API, it doesn't. It's like the data coming from the API is not understood by PHP.

Do you have any idea of what's wrong?

Thanks!

Laurent

Comment: Note you can use `http_build_query($fields)` in place of all that code that builds `$fields_string`.

Comment: Check for error with json_last_error() after calling json_decode. What does it return?

Comment: UTF8 problem : Señora : check `utf8_encode();

Comment: @stefan it returns error 4 which doesn't seem to make any sense :(

Comment: Is what you posted the complete code? Because curl_exec only returns a boolean and outputs the response, unless CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER is set. I don't see this in your code.

Comment: @Stefan Yes!!! This is it! It was right in my face and I couldn't see it, I had commented this line to debug the problem line by line but it was a bad idea. Thank you so much!! You should add the answer so that I can give you the credits for it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to set `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` to true. Only then will `curl_exec` actually return the response, otherwise it will output the response and return a boolean, indicating success or failure.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

if ($result !== false) {
  $response = json_decode($result, true);
  // do something with $response
} else {
  // handle curl error
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I've had very similar issues before and for me the issue was with the encoding of the data returned from an API being unicode. I'm guessing when you do your copy/paste the string you hard-code ends up being a different encoding so it works fine when passed into json_decode.

The PHP docs specify json_decode only works with UTF-8 encoded strings:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

You may be able to use mb_convert_encoding() to convert to UTF-8:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php

Try this before calling json_decode:

```
$result = mb_convert_encoding($result, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: Thanks, it's most likely an encoding issue but I tried to convert to UTF8 but it didn't work. I tried mb_detect_encoding and it says ASCII. I tried iconv but it didn't work either.

Comment: I also tried utf8_encode and when I check the encoding afterwards, it still says ASCII. It's like it's deaf to any encoding changes :(

Answer (score 1):

Like said @Eilert Hjelmeseth you have some special char in your JSON string => "Señora"

Another way to encode a string to UTF8: [utf8_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php) :

```
$result = json_decode(utf8_encode($result),true);
```

Comment: I believe ñ is a valid UTF-8 character. Indeed the OP had that character in their example that did work. Encoded byte is "c3b1" according to this: https://www.fileformat.info/info/charset/UTF-8/list.htm - but I still agree the issue is encoding for the string

Comment: Yes you're right ! I had the same problem with Latin char and the `utf_encode()` resolved it !